# Do until a var is not null

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop

<sup>**Edit a few years on:** this was clearly a terrible approach, at the start of me using C#/.NET. Hopefully this question helps another noob with the same "problem".</sup>

Is this the best way to approach this scenario?

```
while(true)
{
    if(Main.ActiveForm != null)
    {
        Main.ActiveForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Main.SomeMethod));
        break;
    }
}
```

This is performed on a second thread.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for codereview, unless you are having a specific problem or error that you need help with.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield The problem is that if the user switches to another program, there is no longer an ActiveForm. However, SomeMethod still needs to be performed when the user switches back to this program.

Comment: This is almost certainly not the proper approach to solving your problem.  You haven't really explained the underying problem, but odds are you just need to add an event to your main form for when it's created/shown or something along those lines.

Comment: @DannyBeckett so are you saying that the code you included in your question doesn't do what you want, or are you just looking for alternative techniques? "Is there a better way to do this" questions are off-topic for on stackoverflow because they are subjective and often have multiple answers: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield It does do what I want, but as others have pointed out, `while true, if not null, break` isn't good code. The answers below are much better. Close the question if you want, though I see little point now since the answers are there...

Comment: @DannyBeckett Actually, most all of the answers below are just as bad, or at least not much better.

Comment: @Michael Edenfield: almost all `how` questions are somewhat subjective; and stackoverflow is full of them - I think the FAQ guideline shouldn't be taken too literally.  Then again, lots of people feel differently...

Comment: Putting everything else aside, I think writing `Main.ActiveForm` is confusing, because the returned form may not be `Main`. Writing `Form.ActiveForm` will work exactly the same and is clearer.

Comment: This question should be reopened.  It addresses a specific and quite common programming problem and has concrete answers.  It's also rather pointless to close a question *after* it's garnered useful answers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is this the best way to approach this scenario?

Just to clarify, the scenario is "I have a property of reference type; as soon as the property is not null I wish to invoke one of its methods", and the technique is "spin up another thread, busy-wait until the value is not null, invoke, and stop waiting".

The answer to your question is *no*, this is not the best way to approach this scenario. **This is a terrible way to solve this problem** for several reasons.

First, the code is simply wrong. **The C# language makes no guarantee that this code works.** If it works, then it is working by accident, and it can stop working at any time.

There are three reasons that this code is wrong.

The first reason it is wrong is because of the way threads work on modern operating systems. It is possible that the two threads are each assigned to their own processor. When a processor accesses memory on a modern machine, it does not go out to main memory every time. Rather, it fetches hundreds or thousands of nearby values into a cache the first time you hit an address. From then on, it accesses the local cache rather than taking the expensive bus ride back to main memory.  The implications of that should be obvious: if one thread is writing and another thread is reading, then one thread might be writing to one processor cache and the other might be reading from an entirely different processor cache. They can be inconsistent *forever* if nothing forces them to be consistent, and therefore your loop can run *forever* even if the property has been set on another thread.

(And the "backwards" case is also possible; if the value of the property is *now* null, and was set at some time in the past, then it is possible that the second thread is reading the old, stale value and not the fresh null value. It therefore could decide to not wait at all, and invoke the method on a stale value of the property.)

The second reason this code is wrong is because it has a race condition. Suppose someone assigns the property to non-null on thread one, and then thread two reads it as non-null so you enter the body of the "if", and then thread three assigns it back to null, and then thread two reads it as null and crashes.

The third reason this code is wrong is because the compiler -- either the C# compiler or the jitter -- is permitted to "optimize" it so that it stays in the loop forever without doing the test a second time. The optimizer is allowed to analyze the code and realize that after the first time through the loop, if the test fails then *nothing in the rest of the loop can cause it to succeed*. It is permitted to then skip the test the next time through because it "knows" that it cannot succeed. Remember, the optimizer is permitted to make any optimization *that would be invisible in a single-threaded program*.

The optimizer does not actually make this optimization (to my knowledge) but it is permitted to, and a future version could do so. The optimizer can and does make similar optimizations in similar situations.

In order to make this code correct there must be a *memory barrier* in place. The most common technique for introducing a barrier is to make the access "volatile". The memory barrier forces the processor to abandon its cache and go back to main memory, and discourages the compiler from making aggressive optimizations. Of course, properties may not be volatile, and this technique utterly wrecks performance because it eliminates the one of the most important optimizations in modern processors. You might as well be accessing main memory by carrier pigeon, the cost is so onerous compared to hitting the cache.

Second, the code is bad because you are burning an entire processor sitting there in a tight loop checking a property. Imagine a processor is a car. Maybe your business owns four cars. You are taking one of them and driving it around the block non-stop, at high speed, until the mailman arrives. That is a waste of a valuable resource! It will make the entire machine less responsive, on laptops it will chew through battery like there is no tomorrow, it'll create waste heat, it's just bad.

I note however that at least you are marshalling the cross-thread call back to the UI thread, which is correct.

The best way to solve this problem is to not solve it. If you need something to happen when a property becomes non-null, then the best solution is to handle a change event associated with that property.

If you cannot do that then the best solution is to make the action the responsibility of the property. Change the setter so that it does the action when it is set to non-null.

If you can't make it the responsibility of the property, then make it the responsibility of the user who is setting the property. Require that every time the property be set to non-null, that the action be performed.

If you can't do that then the safest way to solve this problem is to NOT spin up another thread. Instead, spin up a timer that signals the main thread every half second or so, and have the timer event handler do the check and perform the action.

Busy-waiting is almost always the wrong solution.

Comment: +1 for `The best way to solve this problem is to not solve it.` You made my day sir!

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer applies to the general case of running some code when a static variable is set to a non-null value, as opposed to the special case of dealing with `ActiveForm`.  *In this special case* there's an existing event fired when this property is first set to a non-null value (`Activated`).

Comment: I think that SO should let upvote an answer two times (at least for some questions)

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is attach an event handler to the `Activated` event of your form.  Add the following inside that form's constructor:

```
Activated += SomeMethod;
```

And it will be fired whenever you re-activate the form after previously using another application.

The primary advantage of this approach is that you avoid creating a new thread just to have it sitting around doing a spinwait (using up a lot of CPU cycles).

Comment: This looks like what the OP really wants; if he needs concurrency, he can always schedule that in the handler.

Comment: There is a difference between this approach and the way the original code “works”. Using `Activated` assumes you know which form will be activated. The original code is more general.

Comment: @svick True, it's not the same code in the general case, but it may work, and it may even be preferable in the event that he only wants to be notified when one particular form is activated.  If he really does need to do this for any form, it's likely feasible to add an event handler to each instance of each form.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this approach, note that you have a race condition: someone else might set `Main.ActiveForm` to null between your test and your `Invoke()` call.  That would result in an exception.

Copy the variable locally before doing any tests to make sure that the variable cannot be made null.

```
while(true)
{
    var form = Main.ActiveForm;

    if(form != null)
    {
        form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Main.SomeMethod));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point.  However,  while(true) if break is a horrible pattern.

Comment: @cadrell0 Another loop style is possible, but I would not be able to use type inference there.  Without knowing the type of the `Main.ActiveForm` field/property, this is the best that I can do.

Comment: @cdhowie It is of type `Form`.

Comment: @cadrel0: yep, but it's a pretty typical pattern in lock-free programming because it ensures you have only one read and thus a consistent state on which to run your tests (assuming you're using volatile or memory barriers and that the object internals are thread-safe, etc)

Answer (score 3):

When you use a loop You are waste CPU.
The beter way to do this is use events:

```
// make event object in some shared place
            var ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// do when form loaded
            ev.Set();

// wait in thread
            ev.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Or more composition-friendly (and potentially faster), use a `Task` with a `TaskCompletionSource` - but yeah, this is a much better idea than manual busy waiting!

Comment: Eamon Nerbonne, your variant should be a top answer

Comment: Well, feel free to edit your answer and include it then, I'm not going to bother duplicating the essence of this answer for that :-).

Comment: This is much better in that it does not burn a processor, but *if the original poster could call ev.Set when the form is loaded, then why couldn't he simply call the method when the form is loaded?* Why get a second thread involved at all?

Comment: @EricLippert As per [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441809/do-until-a-var-is-not-null/14442138#comment20108389_14441809) the `Load` event doesn't fire when he wants to run his code.  The `Activated` event is the one that fires when he wants his code to run, but he did't know of that event, hence [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14442138/1159478).  Having the appropriate event is the key, and there's no need for a `ManualResetEvent` once you have it; the code can just be placed directly as an event handler.

Comment: Eric Lippert, original poster could call ev.Set from Activated event. If in question talking about another thread I asume that he need It. What if he realy need it?

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
while(Main.ActiveForm == null) { }
```

Comment: You might want to append `{}` to have a complete statement.

Comment: Is that correct though? I *don't* want the block to be executed if the var is null. Only when the var *isn't* null. Thanks.

Comment: this is just the idea, not the full implementation.

Comment: Sure; it basically means "do nothing while it's null" - so you'd stick your code after the loop, not in the loop.  Note that it doesn't address race conditions.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that @EamonNerbonne... so there should be a `;` after that `while` statement?

Comment: BTW, while this is a correct solution to the specific question, it's not a good design for - you should be using a `Task` or some other concurrency primitve to wait, not busy waiting.  That's much more efficient, composes better with other such waits,  and doesn't have potential race condition bugs like this design does.  So +1 correct answer, but I'd not use it in practice if I were you :-).

Comment: See @gabba's answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that.

```
while(Main.ActiveForm == null)
{
    //maybe a sleep here ?!
}
Main.ActiveForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Main.SomeMethod));
```